# bootstrap img-responsive is not working for firefox pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am loading my images through CSS using content and they are working fine for Chrome and Safari, but Firefox has an issue with it which forces me to use Pseudo Elements. However, the Pseudo Elements are not working with the `img-responsive` class.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block" id="imgEN" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#imgEN::after  {
content:url("images/banner.png");
    text-align: -moz-center;
}

.img-responsive { 
width:100%;
}
```

How do I make the `img` element to be responsive? It looks fine on bigger resolution, but on smaller resolution/screen, the image will be out from the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `max-width: 100%` to your a tag. Maybe over a class selector or directly as inline style